# Git log, no commits that were reverted

Tags: git

How can I filter out the commits that were reverted in `git log`?

Especially, I have two branches, say `prod` and `dev` and `dev` was mistakenly merged on `prod`, then reverted. Now I am issuing `git log prod..dev` to see all the commits on `dev` and not on `prod`, but I see also the commits that were reverted. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible in a general sense

Comment: I though so too, given the definition of the .. operator, but it was interesting to ask anyway.